# The power and the use of homotopy pullback?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles, pullback

A homotopy commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    W @>\varphi_y>> Y\\
    @V\varphi_xV V   @VgVV\\
    X @>f>> Z,
\end{CD}
is called a homotopy pullback, if there exists a homotopy equivalence $$\varphi: W
\to X \times^h_Z Y$$
satisfying $\varphi_x = p_x \varphi$ and $\varphi_y = p_y \varphi$, as illustrated in the [diagram](http://www.home.uni-osnabrueck.de/mfrankland/Math527/Math527_0308.pdf).

[image]

My understanding is that if $Z$  is an $H$-space (in particular if it is a loop space), then such a homotopy equivalence $\varphi: W
\to X \times^h_Z Y$ is always constructible, based on @Thyone https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2922633/79069.

However, my questions:

> 1. I think one advantage is that it **guarantees that we also have a pullback from $X\times Y$ to $X \times^h_Z Y$ in the 
>      a fiber sequence**
>      $$
>    \Omega Z\to X \times^h_Z Y \to X\times Y\to Z,
>    $$
>      (where $\Omega Z$ is the loop space of $Z$), 
>      based on @Thyone https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2922633/79069.
>      Can we **classify all such possible $X \times^h_Z Y$**, given the data say $W \to X \times Y$? How many classes? (Related to sort of Postnikov classes?)
> 2. What else can we do other than constructing $X \times^h_Z Y \to X\times Y$?
> 3. What are the other advantage and the power of constructing this homotopy equivalence $\varphi: W
>    \to X \times^h_Z Y$?

Note that every homeomorphism is a homotopy equivalence, [but the converse is not true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Homotopy_equivalence).

Comment: I'm not quite sure that is exactly what I wrote in my other post. The homotopy equivalence $\varphi$ exist by the definition, from assumption that the homotopy commutative square is a homotopy pullback. Certainly the space $X\times^h_ZY$ can be given a standard model, and so always exists. To classify them, let $W_1,W_2$ be two homotopy pullbacks for the cospan $(X\rightarrow Z\leftarrow Y)$. Then there is a chain of homotopy equivalences $\varphi_1:W\xrightarrow{\simeq}X\times^h_ZY\xleftarrow{\simeq}W_2:\varphi_2$, so the homotopy pullback is unique up to homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Homotopy pullbacks have a weakly universal property, which is characterised by example 1.2 in the notes you are following. A map $K\rightarrow W$ corresponds exactly with the data of a pair of maps $s:K\rightarrow X$, $t:K\rightarrow Y$ together with a homotopy $F:f\circ s\simeq g\circ t$.

Comment: The advantage of constructing the homotopy equivalence $\varphi$ is that it tells you the square is a homotopy pullback square. There are other characterisations of the notion.

Comment: Thanks! "To classify them, let $W_1,W_2$ be two homotopy pullbacks for the cospan $(X→Z←Y)$. Then there is a chain of homotopy equivalences ... so the homotopy pullback is unique up to homotopy equivalence." 

**Is there a classification of homotopy pullback (unique up to homotopy equivalence) based on a group classification?** like Postnikov class?

Comment: If you identify the homotopy type of the homotopy pullback $W\simeq X\times ^h_ZY$ then you can classify it in any way that is convenient.

Comment: If you want to read about homotopy pullbacks in the context of topological spaces I would recommend Arkowitz's book 'An Introduction to Homotopy Theory', and Strom's Book 'Modern Classical Homotopy Theory'. The books are both well written and contain many useful exercises - especially the latter. They avoid the abstraction of model categories that other notes steer towards, and their presentations of homotopy pullbacks are geared towards applications in unstable homotopy theory.